# How can I make Rebar run Common Test in a release directory?

Tags: erlang, rebar, common-test

I have a Rebar project with a top-level release directory that just includes the component applications as dependencies and contains the reltool configuration.

Some of my applications have Common Test suites in `test` subdirectories, and I can run those tests with `rebar ct`.

Now I want to create a Common Test suite for the entire release.  However, when I run `rebar ct skip_deps=true` in the top-level directory, I just get:

```
Command 'ct' not understood or not applicable
```

How can I make Rebar run my tests?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Rebar has three sets of modules (see [rebar.app](https://github.com/basho/rebar/blob/master/ebin/rebar.app)):

- `any_dir_modules`, which apply to any directory in your project;
- `app_dir` modules, which apply only to directories containing files matching `src/*.app.src` or `ebin/*.app` (see [`rebar_app_utils:is_app_dir/1`](https://github.com/basho/rebar/blob/master/src/rebar_app_utils.erl#L48)); and
- `rel_dir` modules, which apply only to directories containing `reltool.config` or `reltool.config.script` (see [`rebar_rel_utils:is_rel_dir/1`](https://github.com/basho/rebar/blob/master/src/rebar_rel_utils.erl#L49)).

The `rebar_ct` module, which is responsible for running Common Test, is in the `app_dir` category, and your top-level release directory is thus not eligible.

You can work around this by specifying that `rebar_ct` is a plugin, since plugins bypass the module category mechanism.  Put the following line in your `rebar.config`:

```
{plugins, [rebar_ct]}.
```

And you'll get:

```
$ rebar ct skip_deps=true
==> foo (ct)
==> bar (ct)
==> my_rel (ct)
DONE.
Testing src.my_rel: TEST COMPLETE, 0 ok, 0 failed of 0 test cases
```